# structure " noun+ that+ somebody was"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> Urban spirit that I was, I had no more aptitude as a farmer's daughter than my father had as a farmer. (From ACT)

What does the structure "urban spirit that I was" mean? I don't think it is inversion sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction ***X that Y was*** in such contexts is a rather "literary" way of saying ***Y was [an] X***. It's ***always*** followed by a "related" assertion, which in some way naturally follows from the fact of Y being an X - usually, ***because** Y is an X, [some related assertion]*...

> ***Urban spirit that I was**, I had no more aptitude as a farmer's daughter than my father had as a farmer.*
> ...could be paraphrased as...
> ***Being a city-dweller by nature**, I wasn't much of a farmer's daughter, just as my father wasn't much of a farmer.*

---

Alternatively,...

> ***I was an Urban spirit**, **so / thus / therefore** I had no more aptitude as a farmer's daughter than my father had as a farmer.*